# Hidden directories named .bfglF[0-9]{4}T2L1 in my home directory: What are they for?

Tags: macos, filesystem, folders

I listed all the hidden directories in my home directory and noticed four with names like .bfglF7097T2L1. They all have the format .bfglF[0-9]{4}T2L1, store a file named .sysdata, and have "staff" for the group owner.

I've never noticed them before (and I do use Terminal and edit hidden files pretty frequently), even though some are dated as early as 2014. Googling around I can't find a single reference to these folders or what they are used for.

What are they for? I don't like keeping mystery folders but I'm scared to delete them.

PS I'm currently using macOS Mojave.